# Something like SVN for being able to see changes between two instances of the same sql server db?

Tags: database, eclipse, sql-server-2008

We have a dev, qa, staging environment and have issues with db changes not getting merged with code changes and when trying to resolve the problem it would be nice if we could find a way kind of like svn to see what views/tables/stored procedures have been changed added or deleted. Does anyone know of a tool like that exists? Thanks - Duncan Krebs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many commercial tools that can do this. Visual Studio has one, but I feel that [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) is the best. There is also [OpenDBDiff](http://www.codeplex.com/OpenDBiff), but a [comment on the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/377514/430634) that recommends it suggests that it's not as good.

Comment: The only snag is that my SQL Server databases are using Windows Authentication and I can't run OpenDBDiff using runas from the command prompt that lets me pass in my work domain/username. Bummer

Answer (score 1):

[AdeptSQL](http://www.adeptsql.com/)

or

in Visual Studio: Data > Data Compare

or

SQL Compare as mentioned in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

You can track schema changes in SQLServer 2005/2008 with DDL triggers.

1. Make database for capturing all DDL. We call it VCS
2. Make table in this database:

   ```
    CREATE TABLE ddl_log(
       ddl_log_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
       ,ddl_date datetime 
       ,EventType sysname
       ,database_name sysname
       ,schema_name sysname
       ,object_name sysname
       ,ddl xml
   )
   ```
3. For each database you want trace DDL make.

   ```
   ALTER TRIGGER ddl_log 
   ON DATABASE 
   FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS 
   AS
   DECLARE @data XML;
   SET @data = EVENTDATA();
   INSERT VCS.dbo.ddl_log 
       (ddl_date, EventType, database_name, schema_name, object_name, ddl)
   SELECT
      GETDATE() 
      ,@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'sysname')
      ,@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'sysname') 
      ,@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname') 
      ,@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname') 
      ,@data
   ```

You simple version control system in SQLServer.

If you want to integrate it with your VCS:

1. Create PowerShell-script for scripting all changed objects to filesystem. Schedule it.
2. Schedule checkin for your VCS